# Duplicate file searcher that compares contents, not names

Tags: duplicate-files, jpg

I need software that is capable of finding file duplicates. Mostly JPGs, but to a lesser extent I'd also like to find duplicates of PNG, GIF and MP4 files. The problem is, exact matches are not what I'm looking for. I need a way to find duplicates that have different names yet the same file contents.

I have a program called WinMerge that is capable of finding duplicates of files that are exactly the same. I think it does that not just by comparing names, but also by comparing file binaries themselves, although I'm not sure of that. I heard that it's possible to somehow apply complicated filters that allow to customize results, but I can't find specifically what I'm looking for.

So I need help with figuring this problem out, be it a specific way of using WinMerge or some other software entirely. I'd like to be able to at least find matches by size, ignoring the names. Ideally I'd like to find matches by binaries (not necessarily full binaries, just a chunk of it that is sufficient to make the duplicate match a near certainty), ignoring everything else, but I assume that's much more complicated.

Although I doubt something like this is available to regular users, I'm also curious of the possibility to find matches by picture recognition, similarly to how google images does it. I assume it requires pattern recognition and a lot of processing power though, so it's probably out of scope for regular users.

Comment: Have you tried Beyond Compare? https://www.scootersoftware.com

Comment: Read this link: https://blogs.systweak.com/5-duplicate-photo-finder-tools-to-delete-duplicate-photos/

Comment: If some files were identical to the last byte, you could calculate the md5sum of each file and then remove duplicates.